# npm install -g ios-deploy

Tags: unix, ionic-framework

I am trying to install ios deploy onto my mac to use with Ionic.

when I enter command "npm install -g ios-deploy" I get the following errors:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

/usr/local/lib
└── ios-deploy@1.9.0

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy" "--allow-root"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/patrickbentley/npm-debug.log

Comment: try this link : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 4):

sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm ios-deploy

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have `permission denied` problem. As a start try this to see if it works:

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy
```